# Was Roodown in Ferrix?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens, character-identification, andor

While watching "Kassa", the first episode of the Star Wars TV series *Andor* (2022), I noticed, at least, two familiar species from the movie *Star Wars: The Force Awakens* (2015). There are two steelpeckers at Zorby's Western Shiplot and, also, in the streets of Ferrix I spotted a passerby who looks like "Crusher" Roodown.

Regarding the steepeckers, it’s easy to understand that given the carcasses and guano of them are a worthwhile commodity, steelpeckers can be subject of commerce, which explain their appearance in a planet different from their native Jakku, but, Roodown has its characteristic mechanical load-lifter replacement arms. As we all know, Roodown was an unlucky salvager who had his arms cut off by Unkar Plutt's thugs over a misunderstanding and offered his services as a for-hire strong back, thus, there are not much Abednedos without arms hanging around the galaxy.

I checked the canon but there is no mention of him there. I don't know how long the span of life of Abednedos is but if they live long enough, I ask if the character in TFA and Andor are the same.

[image: Still image 1 of Andor Season 1 Episode 1]

[image: Still image 2 of Andor Season 1 Episode 1]

[image: Crusher Roodown from Star Wars The Force Awakens Visual Dictionary]

Comment: So...  39 years before he was shown on Jakku he had already lost his arms?  And later grew them back for Plutt to cut off again?

Comment: Third species from TFA: there's a Luggabeast in B2EMO's first scene. https://www.starwars.com/andor-s1-e1-trivia-gallery Seems like prop reuse more than deliberate references.